# Creating new user welcome tips

Tags: django, cookies

I'd like to create a tooltip bubbles for my site for new users - many other sites do this (most google apps). I'd like to show them for all accounts created within the last week, unless the user specifically 'dismisses' the tip.

I thought about doing this with cookies - ie. set a "-dismissed=True" value that I could check as well as the account creation date and determine whether to show the tips.

However - this doesn't work across browsers, since cookies aren't shared between browsers. So if a user logs into chrome, dismisses the tip then logs in in FF the tip will reappear.

Does anyone know if there is common way to do this sort of thing? Or at least a better way than what i've described?

I'm using browser length sessions so I can't store it in the session.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a user preferences model, with a one-to-one relationship to the main user model, which stores preferences like this. Create an instance when the user entry itself is created, and default the 'show tips' field to True.

You could also use the new custom user model functionality in 1.5 to store this in the user model itself, but that seems like overkill here.